# Exporting inline code to html in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

What I want in org-mode is like the inline code block syntax in Markdown language `X <- 3`. I googled and attempted ([reference](http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-of-code-blocks.html)):

```
src_R{X <- 3}
```

inline in org-mode, but exporting to html (with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>) did not show the inline code. Other code block like `#+begin_src R` stuff works fine, but anyhow there is a warning message while exporting:

```
htmlize.el 1.34 or later is needed for source code formatting [14 times]
```

Could that be the reason ?

Update:

Thanks for @LeVieuxGildas opinion, I installed and loaded the latest `htmlize.el` version 1.43 now and did not get any error message when exporting. But still exporting html can not show inline code part.

system: OS X 10.8.2 ; emacs mac port https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port ; built-in org-mode

Comment: You mean `C-c` **`C-e`** `h`, right ? (Not being sure, I didn't edit that) [This footnote](http://orgmode.org/org.html#fn-114) suggests you probably need to upgrade htmlize, and that upgrading org would do. Is that your answer ? (I have no idea how much the legacy exporter handles html inline code blocks, but maybe the new exporter does a better job with them.)

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas Yes. It's `C-c` `C-e` `h`. I edited and corrected it. As I understand from the footnote, `htmlize` package 1.34 version should be built in org.

Comment: Probably built-in in the most up-to-date version, maybe not in the bundled one you've got.

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas You are right. The built-in version is 7.8.11. And I upgraded org-mode to 7.9.2, the latest version, but it does not help. Same message about `htmlize` showed up.

Comment: [It's in contrib](http://osdir.com/ml/emacs-orgmode-gnu/2010-05/msg00344.html), which for sure is added in your lisp path? Didn't forget to org-reload? I fall short of ideas at this point…

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas ah. You are right again. The `package` install in emacs 24 somehow does not include htmlize.el for org-mode and org-plus-contrib. I downloaded it from org website and loaded it, then there is no error for the `htmlize`. But again, inline code still did not show up. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try `src_R[:exports "code"]{X <- 3}`.

Comment: @artscan Not working. shows: `#+BEGIN_SRC R X <- 3` this time.

Comment: It shows such string for me too. I think it's a bug. Inline `src_<language>` worked in my org files some time ago in early versions of org-mode. But now it works only if `src_<language>` is on a separate line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think we are talking about two things here. If you want to just "show code" like the backticks in Markdown, surround your inline code with equal signs, as in:

```
Write messages in JavaScript using: =console.log(x, y)=
```

However, using the `src_XYZ{abc}` attempts to evaluate that as code and return the results.

Answer (score 3):

Fast and dirty solution is to modify the header arguments in your previous inline code.

```
src_R[:exports code]{X <- 3}
```

In my opinion, inline code is much better than `=code=` or `~code~` because it can be syntax highlighted if you output your org file as Latex file.

Comment: You can make this the default for all inline code blocks by adding the following to the top of your org file:
`#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports code`.